# Carpeta de mi equipo se copio en mi onedrive y quiero sacarla

Tags: archivo, internet

No se porque la carpeta **Documentos** e **Imagenes** de **"Este equipo"** ahora estan en mi onedrive, cuando las borro del onedrive tambien se borran del equipo, no se como sacarlas de ahi, no quiero que borrar algo importante del equipo

Ya e intentado cerrar la sesion del Onedrive personal, pero cuando vuelvo a ingresar las carpetas regresan a ese sitio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No cierres OneDrive. Ve a configuración y defines qué directorios se sincronizan

Comment: Configuraracion/Cuenta/Elegir carpetas  al elegir la carpeta **documentos** o **imagenes** me aparece que no se puede detener la desincronizacion porque son carpetas improtantes para windows

Comment: Es algún tipo de cuenta institucional? Es posible que haya políticas que no puedas sobreescribir (porque la ruta que describes es la que indica [la documentación](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: mi onedrive personal es de un correo normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente en cuenta / elegir carpetas sale esa excepción

El otro camino es en sync y backup, elegir carpetas y detener la sincronización de esos directorios

[image: OneDrive]